# two point block method for solving ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

How to solve the ordinary differential equation 
$$y'(t) = -1000 y(t)+ 999 e^{-t}, \hspace{10mm} 0≤t≤5.$$ 
$y(t)=e^{-t}$, for $t<0$. Using two point block method 
$$hf_{n+1}= \frac{1}{3} (hf_{n+2} - 2y_{n} + 2y_{n+1} )$$ 
and 
$$y_{n+2}= \frac{1}{3} \, (2hf_{n+2}-y_{n}+4y_{n+1} )$$ 
step-size=0.01

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial and edit your post; it's hard to understand now

Comment: Do you want exact solution? If no, what's trouble with block method?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Not the OP, but what's the purpose of the first line? I recognize the second as BDF2, but that hardly can be named as two-point.